# What are the alternatives for Java authentication?

Tags: java, apache-flex, security, authentication

Preferably something that integrates well with a Flex front end. Yes the Spring Security guys say this is possible, but all examples seem to use legacy jsp tag libraries making them half useless as examples. I don't want to spend a month setting up and learning how to use a security tool. I would like a tool which supports using annotations (@RolesAllowed etc), MINIMAL XML, and 'remember-me' features (not cookie based).

Apache Shiro seems to support Flex/Silverlight/Swing as well but I'd like to know if there are any other alternatives that are NOT container specific.

Comment: What type of remember-me are you suggesting when you say you don't want it to be cookie based? Within one session you could use parameters in the url, but between sessions I wouldn't know of a way to store credentials without (flash)cookies.

Comment: Couldn't SharedObject do that?
http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/SharedObject.html
I don't know what the logistics of doing this would be but it'd be nice to ditch container session management altogether using something that doesn't NEED a container (like Shiro?)  I want to be able to deploy to J2EE containers without worry that my security/session functionality is going to break each time, but I also don't want to spend 1/3 of my development time setting such security up.  Isn't that a worthwhile goal?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Turns out [Apache Shiro](http://shiro.apache.org) is actually a simpler and easier to learn solution than Spring security. And no stupid xml configuration is nice.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why Flex should authenticate anything,  after all that is the client side.  Whats stopping someone from decompiling your flash/flex?

For most people Apache Shiro is overkill and they just roll their own.  Which isn't the best idea to be honest.  I have seen a lot of horrible authentication systems over the years.  Cookies are meant to keep track of the session for the client, why use anything else?

**Edit:**
Use spring secuirty for authentication.

Comment: I think you misunderstand, I don't want Flex itself authenticating anything (and swf hacking is exactly the reason I'm looking for real, server-side security). It's only involvement is the fact that remoting (RemoteObject) calls via Blaze or Granite DS are being used rather than simple form submission, which means that jsp tag examples aren't such good examples.

Comment: Also I believe the Spring Security docs talk about an alternative to cookie-based persistence which is more secure (I forget what it's called but I believe it uses a database), and I don't feel cookies integrate very well with a Flex app. And one more thing - authentication isn't so hard (JAAS) but authorization seems to be more problematic.

Comment: @Crusader you are a bit confused.  It is an absolute requirement that you pass a session id to the web server in order to maintain session state.  Weather that state is being kept by a Session Bean or using the database is irrelevant in terms of secuirty.  If this session id is leaked to the attacker though xss or sniffing,  then that account is compromised.  This is why OWASP A3: broken authentication and session management requires the use of HTTPS throughout the entire session.

Comment: I think you're mixing up old-school web development with Rich Internet Application development. Regardless, this is far off topic and not answering the question at all.

Comment: @Crusader - RIA is not much different from old-school development in terms of security. You still have to deal with http(s), and cookies are by far the most common way to authenticate/authorize users. You *can* pass the authentication token in the request instead of a cookie, but then you have to do a bit more work, and its not adding anything to security. And *Cookies don't integrate well with a Flex app* is incorrect - you don't have to do anything to manage cookies. Server will set the cookie, browser will automatically send it with every request, and spring security will do the rest.

Comment: Ok I guess I 'mis-remembered' reading whatever it was in the Spring security docs about cookies, but I still think integrating Spring Security is ridiculously difficult. It took forever just to get basic authentication and authorization working (dependencies are a particularly nasty pain), without even having fancier features like 'remember me' enabled, or using a db to store users. The learning curve just still doesn't cut it. It shouldn't be so difficult.

Comment: @Crusader if you want to make an omelet you have to break some eggs.

Comment: @The Rook I prefer Egg Beaters. =)
Sorry though, there's just WAY too much configuration and too many dependencies using Spring security. How many megs of freakin bloated interdependent jar files does it take to create a simple CRUD app with some reasonable security? :/
I think Shiro's development philosophy is just hard to beat, so I'll have to go with that, enough with the "Spring sub-project" hype bandwagon. I'm not using anything just because it has the word Spring in front of it.

Comment: At the risk of looking like a salesman, I'd suggest checking out Shiro's mission statement and features sections on their webpage to get a feel for what their goals are.  THAT is what I've been looking for in a security framework.  I don't know if their goals are simply different from Spring Security's, or if they just achieve them better, but Shiro is different.

It's great that someone finally "gets it" and is working on a tool with such goals in mind.

https://cwiki.apache.org/SHIRO/about.html
https://cwiki.apache.org/SHIRO/features.html

Answer (score 0):

Spring Security is by far the best tool out there.

BlazeDS is no magic. It is ultimately just a call to the server over HTTP. The Blaze application is just a war file, and has traditional urls. So, to protect the services, you have to protect the urls in your web.xml / spring configuration files.

Essentially, read the documentation of Spring Security/JAAS, and substitute the jsps with the urls of your blaze services.

Spring Security also has support for Roles and authorization. It also has a remember-me functionality, *but* that absolutely uses cookies. You cannot have a remember-me functionality without cookies.

Regarding authentication, it is possible to pass the authentication token as a request parameter instead of a cookie. But cookies are recommended, and are a lot easier to get right.

And finally, security is pointless without using https. You absolutely must use https throughout your application if you care about security.

Comment: I don't understand why everyone says Spring Security is so great (or that Shiro is "overkill") when Spring Security has a massive list of dependencies and a steep learning curve.

Shiro's goal is to be the 'easiest to use', has almost NO dependencies and jar hell, and very little configuration. Contrasted with the Spring xml fetish I just don't understand how someone could say Shiro is overkill. If anything Spring Security probably has more features, but is much more bloated too.

It sounds like these two are the only alternatives out there...